# Honestly confused about where to put ActiveDirectory code/classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've looked up several other answers and really couldn't decide because I'm not sure if this is belongs in the Controller, the Model, creating an App_Code folder.

I'd really like to stay away from creating a separate project.

I currently have 3 Controlles, lots of Models and lots of Views.

I am being assigned a new project to be able to traverse the entire ActiveDirectory.  This code can literally be used on any given page so it isn't specific to a controller.

Where should I put this code?

Controller?  Model? create an App_Code folder and put the class in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Umm... Create a folder at the main project level e.g. `ActiveDirectoryService` and put it there. Problem solved.

When you have the 'service' ready, you can use it freely in controllers, by injecting it when needed.

Comment: This. Or, if you may have other services that could be used by various controllers, create a top-level Services folder, then put classes for each of the services there, starting with your ActiveDirectoryService.cs

Answer (score 5):

I know you aren't keen, but in my opinion the cleanest way is to create a DLL project in your current solution and put your code in there and reference it from your main project.  That keeps it completely separate from anything else...

Comment: This, I would not make a separate project for only this service though. I would call the project something generic so you can put all kinds of services in there and still keep it nicely separated from the main project.